# How to pass an Array to function as a parameter in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function, arguments

Am trying to pass an array as a parameter to a function. I tried as AnyObject and Generic T. Am not able to fix the issue. I have attached my tries to your reference.

```
Calling Function:
parsedData(&resultsArray)

Function:
with Generic
func parsedData <T> (inout parsedResults : T) {

        print("ParsedResults: \(parsedResults)")

        let array = parsedResults

        let modelObj = array[0] as? DataModel
        print("Title: \(modelObj.title) Desc: \(modelObj.desc) Date: \(modelObj.date)")

    }

without Generic:
func parsedData (parsedReuslts: AnyObject) {

        print("ParsedResults: \(parsedReuslts)")

        let modelObj = array[0] as? DataModel
        print("Title: \(modelObj.title) Desc: \(modelObj.desc) Date: \(modelObj.date)")

    }

Where am calling this func: parsedData(resultsArray)// Here am getting error message like "Cannot invoke 'parsedData' with an argument list of type '([Any])'"
```

Can anyone please help where am going in a wrong way? How to fix this issue? 
Looking forward your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `[DataModel]` as type for function parameter

Something like

```
func parsedData(parsedResuls: [DataModel]) {


}
```

Comment: I have array of models in XML Parser delegate. I have to pass the array to somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand. The array of models has `DataModel` objects in it, right? So the parameter type would be `parsedResuls: [DataModel]`. Are you asking a new question?

Comment: In NSXMLParser didEndElement delegate I stored the model objects in an array called "resultsArray". Once after the parser completion, I need to pass this array to a function called "parsedData".In Objective-C we declare the parameter (NSMutableArray *) result.Then we can pass the array as a parameter. But, in swift I confused how to pass the array to a function. Hope you understand my problem.I changed the parameter as per your answer and still am getting the error "Cannot invoke 'parsedData' with an argument list of type '([Any])'". And the fun is "func parsedData(parsedResuls: [DataModel])"

Comment: when invoking the function do this `parsedData(resultsArray as [DataModel])`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was crash and the error message is "fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C". Actually I declared the resultsArray in this way "var resultsArray : [Any] = Array()". Because have to store any type of object. Is it the cause of problem? Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: If you save `DataModel` in your resultsArray, can't you just declare it like `var resultsArray : [DataModel] = []`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91567/discussion-between-yuvaraj-m-and-shamas-s).